# Blur Shader: Can I use one Framebuffer for the horizontal and vertical pass?

Tags: opengl, shaders, glsl, blur

I have set up my blur shader with the following header:

```
#version 400
in vec2 texCoord;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform vec2 resolution;
uniform float radius;
uniform vec2 dir;

layout (location = 0) out vec4 out_color;
void main() { *some code*; out_color = vec4(*some code*); }
```

The vertical pass is working well but I would like to use the same Framebuffer for both passes.

My idea was to create Color **Attachment1** and Color **Attachment2**. In the first pass, **Attachment1** is the target (out_color) attachment. Now I want the second pass to bind **Attachment1** to the sampler2D (u_texture) and write the resulting pixels (out_color) into **Attachment2**.

If there is any possibility to read from one **Attachment** and write to another, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Well, I tried a bit with glDrawBuffers and found a working solution.

Before the second pass starts, I simply switched the shader output:

```
layout (location = 0) out vec4 out_color;
```

to the second attachment (**Attachment2**) simply by writing:

```
GL.DrawBuffer(DrawBufferMode.ColorAttachment2);
```

This line of code will change the target of the 1st shader output (layout location = 0) so that it writes to **Attachment2**.
Also, I restore the DrawBuffer after the second pass, so the first pass won't have any problems.